# Trying to get a value from another class but isn't running the top subclass

Tags: java

I am working on a small project of mine it is not running as expected. When I am trying to call `aTicket.getCost()` and it is giving resultant value as `0`, I'm trying to run it via the subclass `public double cost` first I am trying to save the cost into `aTicket.setCost()`. It should go through the if statements then override the current default value of `0`.

I have another class for storing the Customers age, name and checks if they are a student. This is called in the `Ticket` class.

Here is my `Ticket` class:

```
public class Ticket 
{

    private Customer aCustomer;
    private double cost;

    public double cost()
    {
        Ticket aTicket = new Ticket();

        if (aCustomer.getAge() >= 18 && aCustomer.getAge() <= 64)
        {
            aTicket.setCost(10);

            if (aCustomer.getStudent() == true && aCustomer.getAge() >= 10 && aCustomer.getAge() <= 25)
            {
                aTicket.setCost(10 * 0.15);
            }
            else if (aCustomer.getStudent() == true && aCustomer.getAge() > 25)
            {
                aTicket.setCost(10 * 0.10);
            }
            else if (aCustomer.getStudent() == false && aCustomer.getAge() > 64)
            {
                aTicket.setCost(10 * 0.07);
            }
        }

        else if (aCustomer.getAge() < 18)
        {
            aTicket.setCost(7);

            if (aCustomer.getStudent() == true && aCustomer.getAge() >= 10 && aCustomer.getAge() <= 25)
            {
                aTicket.setCost(7 * 0.15);
            }
            else if (aCustomer.getStudent() == true && aCustomer.getAge() > 25)
            {
                aTicket.setCost(7 * 0.10);
            }
            else if (aCustomer.getStudent() == false && aCustomer.getAge() > 64)
            {
                aTicket.setCost(7 * 0.07);
            }
        }

    return aTicket.getCost();
    }

    public Ticket(double cost)
    {
        this.setCost(cost);
    }

    public Ticket()
    {
        this.setCost(0);
    }

    public void setCost(double cost)
    {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public double getCost()
    {
        return cost;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return "TOTAL COST: $" + getCost();
    }

}
```

Here is my subclass calling Ticket class:

```
public static Ticket IssueTicket()
{
    Ticket aTicket = new Ticket();


    System.out.println(aTicket.getCost());

    return aTicket;
}
```

The console asks for their name, age, and checks if they're a student or not. But it always prints out `0` when `aTicket.getCost()` is called.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried to debug in order to see what happens?

Comment: @PatriceBernassola I have but I don't know how to figure out how to make `public double cost` to run

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that is because `aCustomer` is `null`, you did not set the acustomer in `Ticket()` constructor. It always prints out 0 when aTicket.getCost() is called because

```
public Ticket() {
    this.setCost(0);
}
```

You should set the Customer in constructor so your if else can determine their age

EDIT MY CODE FOR TICKET and Customer

Ticket class:

```
public class Ticket {

    private Customer aCustomer;
    private double cost;

     public Ticket(double cost) {
         this.setCost(cost);
     }

     public Ticket() {
         this.setCost(0);
     }

    public double cost() {
        Ticket aTicket = new Ticket();
        if (aCustomer.getAge() >= 18 && aCustomer.getAge() <= 64) {
            aTicket.setCost(10);
            if (aCustomer.getStudent() && aCustomer.getAge() >= 10 && aCustomer.getAge() <= 25) {
                 aTicket.setCost(10 * 0.15);
             }
             else if (aCustomer.getStudent() && aCustomer.getAge() > 25) {
                 aTicket.setCost(10 * 0.10);
             }
             else if (!aCustomer.getStudent() && aCustomer.getAge() > 64) {
                 aTicket.setCost(10 * 0.07);
             }
         }
         else if (aCustomer.getAge() < 18) {
             aTicket.setCost(7);
             if (aCustomer.getStudent() && aCustomer.getAge() >= 10 && aCustomer.getAge() <= 25) {
                 aTicket.setCost(7 * 0.15);
             }
             else if (aCustomer.getStudent() && aCustomer.getAge() > 25) {
                 aTicket.setCost(7 * 0.10);
             }
             else if (!aCustomer.getStudent() && aCustomer.getAge() > 64) {
                 aTicket.setCost(7 * 0.07);
             }
         }
         return aTicket.getCost();
     }

     public void setCost(double cost) {
         this.cost = cost;
     }

     public double getCost() {
         return cost;
     }

     public String toString() {
         return "TOTAL COST: $" + getCost();
     }
 }
```

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private boolean student;

    public Customer(String name, int age, boolean student) {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setStudent(student);
    }

    public Customer() {
        this.setName("Unknown");
        this.setAge(0);
        this.setStudent(false);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setStudent(boolean student) {
        this.student = student;
    }

    public boolean getStudent() {
        return student;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "CUSTOMER DETAILS: " + getName() + " age: " + getAge() + " Student? ";
    }
}
```

This is my main for the customer class:

```
private static Customer customerDetailsInput() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Customer aCustomer = new Customer();
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Cinema Ticket Purchasing System\n");
    System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
    aCustomer.setName(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Please enter your age:");
    aCustomer.setAge(input.nextInt());
    String student;
    System.out.println("Are you a student (Y/N):");
    student = input.next();
    if (student.equals("Y") || student.equals("y")) {
        aCustomer.setStudent(true);
    }
    else if (student.equals("N") || student.equals("n")) {
        aCustomer.setStudent(false);
    }
    return aCustomer;
}
```

Regarding your edit, First u dont have to declare

```
Ticket aTicket = new Ticket();
```

in your own class.

Second, as I mentioned, you need a Ticket constructor with customer as parameter to initialize your customer in ticket.

You dont have to use set cost in ticket, just use cost equal to set the code.

This works for me:

```
public static Ticket issueTicket() {
    Ticket t = new Ticket(customerDetailsInput());
    System.out.println("cost: " + t.toString());
    return null;
}
```

this one worked

Comment: Would I do this by going `public double cost(Customer aCustomer` and  `public static Ticket IssueTicket(Customer aCustomer)` then in the main `IssueTicket(Customer aCustomer)`?

Comment: what about public Ticket(Customer aCustomer)
    {
        this. aCustomer = aCustomer;
    }

Comment: I tried that @HuiWen Yeoh but in `public static Ticket IssueTicket()` this is wrong `Ticket aTicket = new Ticket(aCustomer);`

Comment: Yes but don't want to share it to the public it's my own project.

Comment: the ticket and customer part